# Browsers suddenly asking me to login with username and password for most websites

Tags: security, browser

My browsers keeps throwing me a 'login to *website*:80 - Your password will be sent unencrypted' popup when trying to access most websites, including Google.

I've checked my girlfriends computer and hers has started doing this too...

Very concerning, does anyone know why this is happening? I have googled but can't find this problem. No amount of refreshing, cache emptying seems to solve the issue. Happening in all browsers. Same looking popup (see below).

If I hit cancel i get a 401:

401 Unauthorized

Your client does not have permission to get URL /cgi-bin/index.asp from this server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a half answer...

After resetting my router the issue has stopped.

It would be great if somebody could comment as to why this was happening.

Comment: Look up your brand of router (and seriously consider posting it here). Your router may have been infected but with a temporary infection of some sort. This applies especially if you have a customized router with open source code.

Comment: @TheSatinKnight - Thanks so much for replying. It's a standard TalkTalk DSL 7382 Router.